# Android Monitor- Monitors not working

Tags: android-studio, adb, monitoring

I have a problem with android monitors (CPU,GPU, ... )

[image: this monitors]

I use Genymotion and no run. Monitors do nothing.

I have enabled adb integration.

But not run.

why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finded the problem.

in the second "menu" I need find your pacage. for scanning cpu/gpu..

on the screen upper I have red title No debbugable. and here i need find pacage my running app.